# Passing class objects as parameters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parameter-passing

Hey so I am new to Xcode and I have a few questions.

I want to make a Grade-book Application, that implements quite a few classes. For example, I created a class called "AssignmentList" which basically stores a list of assignment grades in the form of a `double`.

Another class, called "Course" has a `NSMutableArray` of AssignmentList objects.

If I wanted to retrieve an AssignmentList parameter for a course, my Java instinct would tell me to make a getter method like this:

```
-(AssignmentList)getAssignmentList(Course);
```

However, I can't seem to do that in Objective C, and only works when I do this:

```
-(id)getAssignmentList(Course);
```

How do I go about this? I wanted to create a `UITableView` listing all the AssignmentList objects of a Course, but I can't even set a `UITableViewCell` with the name of the AssignmentList because it won't let me use the getName method I made, because getName only works for an AssignmentList object, but the getAssignmentList method returns an (`id`).

Comment: You are missing * here

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an AssignmentList is a class with instances and not some kind of collection (e.g. an NSArray of Assignments), then your declaration needs to be something like:

```
-(AssignmentList *) getAssignmentList:(Course *) course;
```

The `*` is important: in Objective-C you don't really pass around objects, you pass around pointers to objects. (Well, that's true in Java, too, but you don't have to be explicit about it.)

When you declare something `id` that means *pointer to something of unknown type* so you don't need the `*`.

Comment: For a slight refinement of this, if the `Course` owns the `AssignmentList` array, I would expect this method to be part of the `Course` class and not need to be given a `Course` object.  (It might need some parameter to indicate **which**  list....)